# how many times the array contains the value?

Tags: java, arrays

It is a simple program to find if input x value is in the array or not.
The user types numbers into the array, after that types a number to count **how many times** this numbers repeats in the array.
What I have:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] mas = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Input of mas["+i+"]: ");
            int n = sc.nextInt();
        }
        valueX(mas);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
           System.out.println("Would you like to continue (1=yes, 0=no)?");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        if (n==1) {
            valueX(mas);
        }
        if (n==0) {
            System.out.println("Program terminated");
            sc.close();
            break;

        } 
        }

    }
    public static void valueX(int mas1[]){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Input x: ");
        int x =scanner.nextInt();
        int count =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas1.length; i++) {
            if (x==mas1[i]) {
                count++;
            }


        }
         System.out.println("Value "+x+" appears "+count+" time(s) in the array.");
    }
```

The valueX metod should do this work but it does not.
What I expect to get:

```
Input of mas[0]: 2
Input of mas[1]: 2
Input of mas[2]: 3
Input of mas[3]: 4
Input of mas[4]: 2
Input x: 2
Value 2 appears 3 time(s) in the array.
```

But what my code does:

```
Input of mas[0]: 2
Input of mas[1]: 2
Input of mas[2]: 3
Input of mas[3]: 4
Input of mas[4]: 2
Input x: 2
Value 2 appears **0** time(s) in the array.
```

Could you please find the mistake ?

Comment: Try printing the mas array so you make sure you iterate it correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not storing the input value in array so your array has all `0`(default value of `int`) value, hence the issue

```
    int[] mas = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Input of mas["+i+"]: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        mas[i] = n;
        //^^^^^^^^

    }
```